# Code to Select the Worksheet using textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small userform with two textbox in it. What I need is that when I press the submit button it will run a code for me and at the end it should activate the worksheet whose name is entered in textbox2. So far I have gone through all the phases but unable to complete the last step.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Defining the Variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim row As ListRow
Dim sample As Worksheet

'Assigning the Variables
Set ws = UserForm2.txt2.Value
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add(Alwaysinsert:=True)

'Setting Up the Range and Enter Data in Table
lastrow = ws.Range("A:A").End(xlUp).row
row.Range(1, 1).Value = txt1.Value

'Create the New Sheet for the Account Head Created
Sheets("Summary-CH-Sample").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set sample = ActiveSheet
sample.Name = UserForm2.txt1.Value

'Entering the Sheet name in Newly Created Sheet
With ActiveSheet
Range("A7").Value = "Summary of " & UserForm2.txt1.Value
End With
```

Kindly help me out.

Thanks
Salman Khan

Answer (score 0):

if your referring to a worksheet in the same workbook where the macro resides then you should use

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UserForm2.txt2.Value)
```

here's your code with that statement along with some other small suggestions

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Defining the Variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim row As ListRow
Dim sample As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Dim txt1Val As String, txt2Val As String '<== use variables to collect data from UserForm, to avoid multiple references to objects

With Me ' thus referring to UserForm2
    txt1Val = .txt1.Value
    txt2Val = .txt2.Value
End With

'Assigning the Variables
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(txt2Val) '<==
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set row = tbl.ListRows.Add(Alwaysinsert:=True)

'Setting Up the Range and Enter Data in Table
With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row '<== but where do you use it?
End With

row.Range(1, 1).Value = txt1Val ' <==

'Create the New Sheet for the Account Head Created
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary-CH-Sample").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) '<== always specify the workbook you want to work with. here I specified ThisWorkbook. myabe you want ActiveWorkbook
Set sample = ActiveSheet
sample.name = txt1Val

'Entering the Sheet name in Newly Created Sheet
With ActiveSheet
    Range("A7").Value = "Summary of " & txt1Val
End With


End Sub
```